# Getting dates of current week/month react useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

I have a `useEffect(() => {`, and I also am using `<FullCalendar` like this:

```
<FullCalendar
        // CUSTOM BUTTON
        plugins={[ timeGridPlugin ]}
        datesSet={(dateInfo) => {
          console.log(dateInfo.start) //start of the range the calendar date
        }}
```

Now, what I need is that on the `useEffect` (on page load), I can call `datesSet` and get the dates into the `useEffect`.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

`datesSet` is a fullCalendar option, which allows you to specify a callback function to be run whenever fullCalendar's current date range changes. So it's effectively an event handler..therefore, you can't call it directly. Instead, fullCalendar will run the callback whenever the relevant internal event happens.

If you want to get the calendar's current date range at other times, then you can use its `view` property, which returns a View object, which in turn contains the current start and end dates.

```
var view = calendar.view;
var start = view.currentStart;
var end = view.currentEnd;
```

Documentation:

- view property: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-view
- View object: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object
- datesSet: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/datesSet